# Modifier keys cannot be mapped to regular keys on USB keyboard with udev

Tags: usb, keyboard, systemd, udev, keyboard-layout

Using an hwdb file, `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/99-keyboard.hwdb`, I can remap the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key on my USB keyboard as the  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key:

```
keyboard:usb:v*p*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_700e2=leftctrl
```

This also works when I try to remap the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key as the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

But when trying to remap <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> as the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, it does not work:

```
keyboard:usb:v*p*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70039=leftctrl
```

Running `evtest` indicates that it should be working:

```
Event: time 1399438713.757082, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70039
Event: time 1399438713.757082, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL), value 1
Event: time 1399438713.757082, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1399438713.885078, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e0
Event: time 1399438713.885078, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL), value 0
Event: time 1399438713.885078, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

It also does not work on other non-modifier keys I tried, such as <kbd>Z</kbd>.

I have also tried to map <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to the left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key on a non-USB keyboard, as such:

```
keyboard:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svn*:pn*:pvr*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_3a=leftctrl
```

This works perfectly.  I tried udev versions 208 and 212 with a few different USB and non-USB keyboards, on Fedora 20 and on Arch Linux.

How can I remap a non-modifier key such as <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to a modifier key such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on a USB keyboard using **udev**?

### Update

If the left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is itself remapped to another key, then the remapped key starts to work as the left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.  For example:

```
keyboard:usb:v*p*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_700e0=grave
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70035=esc
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70039=leftctrl
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70029=capslock
```

This behaviour is different from a non-USB keyboard, where both the remapped key and the original key may remain as a modifier.

Comment: Just clicking through the *Related Questions* link on the side here and my belief is many were *very* related. Specifically look for one about a kernel parameter, another discussing `xmodmap,` also one from Gilles and one from slm. I would also question what your firmware might or might not actively do to your USB input - boxers often package - and enable by default - certain legacy compatibility behaviors for handling the difference between USB inputs and the older, and much more reliable, parallel inputs.

Comment: i've been going mad with this! your updated text really solved this mystery! thanks!

Comment: using the left control as another key wasn't working for me so i remaped it to rightctrl and remaped right control to something else: `keyboard:usb:v*p*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70039=leftctrl
 KEYBOARD_KEY_700e0=rightctrl
 KEYBOARD_KEY_700e4=esc
`

Comment: also, for reference, your bug report https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=78408